# Create new array from two separate arrays by counting duplicates php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called Array1. This contains names such as Array1 = "John, Ali, Ali, Mark, Susan, Susan, Susan, Ali, Julie, John" etc.

I would like to:
1st - count how many times each name appears in Array1
2nd - create a separate array removing duplicates from Array1
3rd - add to second array the count of duplicates.

Thus my final array would look like as such:

```
Array2 =
John => 2
Ali => 3
Mark => 1
Susan => 3
Julie =>1
```

How would i go about this? Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php - all of the things you want to do can be done using built-in functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = ["John", "Ali", "Ali", "Mark", "Susan", "Susan", "Susan", "Ali", "Julie","John"];
print_r(array_count_values($array1));
?>
```

Output

```
Array ( [John] => 2 [Ali] => 3 [Mark] => 1 [Susan] => 3 [Julie] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all that with PHP's built-in functions:

https://3v4l.org/OHgPv

```
$array = ['Susan', 'Mark', 'Susan', 'Stephan'];
```

> count how many times each name appears in Array1

```
$valuesCounted = array_count_values($array);
```

> create a separate array removing duplicates from Array1

```
$unique = array_unique($array);
```

> add to second array the count of duplicates.

```
$duplicates = array_filter($valuesCounted, function($var) {
    return $var > 1;
});

$final = $unique;
$final['duplicates'] = $duplicates;
```

Putting it all together:

```
<?php

$array = ['Susan', 'Mark', 'Susan', 'Stephan'];

$valuesCounted = array_count_values($array);


$unique = array_unique($array);

$duplicates = array_filter($valuesCounted, function($var) {
    return $var > 1; // We only want to have values in our array where the value was found more than once i.e. is a duplicate.
});

$final = $unique;
$final['duplicates'] = $duplicates;

var_dump($final);
```

**Output for 7.1.25 - 7.3.2**

> array(4) {
>    [0]=>
>    string(5) "Susan"
>    [1]=>
>    string(4) "Mark"
>    [3]=>
>    string(7) "Stephan"
>    ["duplicates"]=>
>    array(1) {
>      ["Susan"]=>
>      int(2)
>    }
>   }

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

`array_count_values()` for rescue :)

```php
$array = explode(', ' , 'John, Ali, Ali, Mark, Susan, Susan, Susan, Ali, Julie, John');

$count = array_count_values( $array );
```

Comment: This outputs the following: Array ( [John] => 1 [ Ali] => 3 [ Mark] => 1 [ Susan] => 3 [ Julie] => 1 [ John] => 1 ). John appears twice

Answer (score 0):

a full explanation of all the above question

```
 <?php
$testArray = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'beer',
    'coffee',
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'beer',
    'coffee',
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'beer',
    'coffee',
];


$countArray = count($testArray);

$duplicatesRemoved = array_unique($testArray);
$vals = array_count_values($testArray);

print_r($vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check array_count_value function. It will work for you very well. Check below code:

```
$collection = array("Geeks", "for", "Geeks", "Geeks", "Welcome", "for");

$collectionValCounter = array_count_values($collection); // This will print all values with their apperance counter.

$collectionUnique = array_values(array_flip($collectionValCounter)); //Unique values with reset keys.
print_r($collectionValCounter); 
print_r($collectionUnique);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the thing you want i think:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach {$array1 as $name}{
    if (array_key_exists($name, $array2)) {
        $array2[$name] = $array2[$name] + 1;
    } else {
        $array2[$name] = 1;
    }
}
```

Greetings, Kai

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use build in PHP function

```
array_count_values()
```

For Example

```
$array1 = array('john','john', 'Ali');


$array2 = array_count_values($array);


print_r($array2);
```

> Results:

```
Array ( [john] => 2 [Ali] => 1 )
```